# Sum of angles between vectors

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to prove some problem, but I need to check this statement first:
for any three vectors 
$\ \vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$ in $\ \mathbb{R}^d$, I should have $\ \angle(\vec{u},\vec{v})+\angle(\vec{u},\vec{w})+\angle(\vec{v},\vec{w})\le360^{\circ}$ where $\ \angle(\vec{x},\vec{y})$ denotes the angle between $\ \vec{x}$ and $\ \vec{y}$

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true, the sum of the angles is less than 360 unless they are coplanar.
Here is a sketch of the proof:
The angles don't depend on how long the vectors are, so take them all to have
length V, and place their tails together at the origin O, and call their heads
A, B, C. ABC forms a triangle in a plane. Drop a perpendicular from O to that 
plane, reaching it at D, and let the length of OD be d. 
    Note the length of AD, BD, and CD are all L= sqrt(V^2-d^2), and so are equal
and less than V (unless d=0, in which case the three vectors are coplanar). 
But OAB and DAB are both isosceles triangles, so the lenght of AB is both
2L sin (\angle ADB /2) and 2V sin (\angle AOB /2), so as V>L, \angle AOB<\angle ADB. The same holds for the other two sides, so the sum of the angles at O is
less than the sum of the three angles at D, which is 360 if D is within the
triangle and less if it is outside.
     Fuller details at  http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~shapiro/618/sum3ang.pdf

Comment: Please, format using Tex/Latex.